# How to revert accidental page unghosting?

Tags: 2010, development, sharepoint-designer, managed-metadata, ghosting

How can I resore ghosting of a page back if I accidentally unghosted it?

Will its deleting and recreating restore ghosting and remove copy of changed page from database?

Update:
Searched for quite a time om the internet and in SPD 2010 for "Reset to Site Definition" option.

It is not in the editing (or editor) of a page ASPX (what could have been expected where I've done changes) but on ribbon of settings page of a view page in SPD (Sharepoint Designer) 2010, under Page tab, immediately upon entering by clicking the entry in the list of "Site Pages".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using SharePoint Designer, just right-click on the file and click "Reset to Site Definition" this will remove the ghosting (now called "Customizing" in 2010), remove that artifact from the content DB, and revert back to the file system version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with the Publishing Site, you would need to take a different road, simpler (in my perspective) - you need to re-attach the Page to the Page Layout and the customization will be discarded.

To reset simple Web Part pages you follow this guide http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/reset-a-customized-page-to-the-site-definition-HA010174145.aspx#BM4 or via Powershell here http://blog.brainlitter.com/2012/02/19/how-to-reset-all-sp-2010-site-pages-to-default-definitions-with-powershell/

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to ask another subquestion - whether deleting and (re)creating a page anew would delete the old one from content database (for files that are usually being ghosted)

Comment: Is always making a copy of the old one renaming it, so no.